# How to Access action creators names with auto-complete in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I am using react and redux with typescript lately and it's awesome.

I can access my store state inside useAppSelector( [as specified in react-redux official document](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript) ) with auto-complete option which speeds-up development time, but I can't access my action creators names with auto-complete inside my useAppDispatch hook.

The reason is I am using redux-thunk middleware in my App, so I have to use ThunkDispatch to type AppDispatch, which has an AnyAction type for action.

```
//react-redux document
import {ThunkDispatch} from 'redux-thunk';
import {AnyAction} from 'react-redux';

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, any, AnyAction>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Currently I export an object which contains all my action creators, and importing it inside any component gives me their names.
like This:

```
// inside actions.ts
const AppActions = {
   action1: () => {},
   action2: () => {},
   ...
}

export default AppActions;


// inside index.tsx
import AppActions from 'actions.ts'

// here i can access them like 
AppActions.action1()
```

So is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there so maybe can you post your store ts file ? then

you will export AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

then in your hooks for

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

Then use it in your app like

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
dispatch(YOU SHOULD SEE YOUR STORE ACTIONS OPTIONS)
```

Comment: I have typed `AppDispatch` correctly, just like the document says and you've pointed here. But what do you mean about `useAppDispatch = () => useAppDispatch()` ? I think you  mean `export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()`.If so I have done that, and yet I can see no action option inside my `dispatch` function.

Comment: sorry I mean export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>(); I fixed the typo and then you import useDispatch from react-redux

Comment: yes I figured. Done that and no options available inside `dispatch` function. And the reason is because I use `redux-thunk` middleware in my app and because of that I have to type my `AppDispatch` like so `type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, any, AnyAction>`. And that `AnyAction` is the reason for all of this.